# SSIS Connection Manager Not Storing SQL Password

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I used to have a DTS package that used SQL Server authentication. The userid password was stored in the package itself. Now that I have moved to SSIS, the password is not getting stored to the package. I saw [SSIS Connection Manager passwords](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c720e694-2f58-483a-9cd7-3feb7de2db7b/ssis-connection-manager-passwords?forum=sqlintegrationservices) when I googled the problem, but no one seems to have given a good resolution.

Comment: Yeah I think we need to go for windows auth... thanks all

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This question points to the Microsoft article *[SSIS package does not run when called from a SQL Server Agent job step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/integration-services/ssis-package-doesnt-run-when-called-job-step)*:

Here are the proposed solutions - have you evaluated them?

> - Method 1: Use a SQL Server Agent proxy account. Create a SQL Server Agent proxy account. This proxy account must use a credential that lets SQL Server Agent run the job as the account that created the package or as an account that has the required permissions.
>
>   This method works to decrypt secrets and satisfies the key requirements by user. However, this method may have limited success because the SSIS package user keys involve the current user and the current computer. Therefore, if you move the package to another computer, this method may still fail, even if the job step uses the correct proxy account.
>   Back to the top
> - Method 2: Set the SSIS Package `ProtectionLevel` property to `ServerStorage`. Change the SSIS Package ProtectionLevel property to ServerStorage. This setting stores the package in a SQL Server database and allows access control through SQL Server database roles.
>   Back to the top
> - Method 3: Set the SSIS Package `ProtectionLevel` property to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword. Change the SSIS Package `ProtectionLevel` property to `EncryptSensitiveWithPassword`. This setting uses a password for encryption. You can then modify the SQL Server Agent job step command line to include this password.
> - Method 4: Use SSIS Package configuration files. Use SSIS Package configuration files to store sensitive information, and then store these configuration files in a secured folder. You can then change the `ProtectionLevel` property to `DontSaveSensitive` so that the package is not encrypted and does not try to save secrets to the package. When you run the SSIS package, the required information is loaded from the configuration file. Make sure that the configuration files are adequately protected if they contain sensitive information.
> - Method 5: Create a package template. For a long-term resolution, create a package template that uses a protection level that differs from the default setting. This problem will not occur in future packages.

Comment: I saw that that link - it doesnt deal with this particular issue. My problem is previously in a DTS connection you can store the user id/password right there inside the package but in SSIS apparently we cannot. The link is talking about running a package from a job in sql agent.

Comment: Maybe you could set the DTS to use NTLM and let it pass thru from the proxy account.

Comment: Not sure if that option is there though.

Comment: Should the password from package configuration update connection manager at design time? How is it even supposed to work?

Comment: What's the situation with the `Package Deployment Model` and sensitive project-level Parameters? Are these saved? Is there a setting for them?

Comment: @OpenSource If this doesn't deal with your particular issue, why did you mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 29):

You can store the password in the configuration string by going to properties and adding `password=yourpassword`, **but it's very important to put a space after the `;` on the line before `password` and after the `;` on the `password` line**, as shown below:

```
Data Source=50.21.65.225;User ID=vc_ssis; 
password=D@mc317Feo; 
Initial Catalog=Sales;
Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;
Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;
Application Name=SSIS-PKG_CustomerData-{2A666833-6095-4486-C04F-350CBCA5C49E}IDM11.Sales.dev;
```

Answer (score 10):

I use a variable to store the entire connection string and pass it into the ConnectionString expression. This  overwrites all settings for the connection and allows you store the password.

Answer (score 6):

The designed behavior in SSIS is to prevent storing passwords in a package, because it's bad practice/not safe to do so.

Instead, either use Windows auth, so you don't store secrets in packages or config files, or, if that's really impossible in your environment (maybe you have no Windows domain, for example) then you have to use a workaround as described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918760 (Sam's correct, just read further in that article). The simplest answer is a config file to go with the package, but then you have to worry that the config file is stored securely so someone can't just read it and take the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the configuration file in the project, set ID and password there, so that you execute the package

Answer (score 0):

Check the text contents of the connection manager file itself, the password field might be configured in the Project.params file, in which case entering the password into the connection manager window will cause it to not save.

Comment: Helps if you mention how to access the connection manager file.

Answer (score -1):

It happened with me as well and fixed in following way:

Created expression based connection string and saved password in a variable and used it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simpler option that works when I encounter this.

After you create the connection, select the connection and open the Properties. In the Expressions category find Password. Re-enter the password and hit Enter. It will now be saved to the connection.

Answer (score -1):

Try storing the connection string along with the password in a variable and assign the variable in the connection string using expression.I also faced the same issue and I solved like dis.

Answer (score -2):

There is easy way of doing this. I don't know why people are giving complicated answers.

Double click SSIS package. Then go to connection manager, select DestinationConnectionOLDB and then add password next to login field.

Example: `Data Source=SysproDB1;User ID=test;password=test;Initial Catalog=ASBuiltDW;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Auto Translate=false;`

Do same for SourceConnectionOLDB.