# XML Configuration File error in SSIS Package

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I've been working with SSIS packages and I'm currently stuck in this problem. I've been developing using a connection String that I wrote in a Package Variable and that value goes to the Connection Mannager through an Expression. Something like this: **@[User::Connection]**

It was working great for debugging. Since I needed to call some stored procedures inside Script tasks and Script Components, I would just call the Package variable as the string connection to the database. Since I'm new to the ETL world (less than a month) and I've been doing some packages (6 actually), it was just recently I read that I should save my ConnectionString in a xml file and store things like user, password there(Since production server will probbably have different user account, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745281/error-while-executing-ssis-package-from-job/15747606#15747606) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832456/ssis-connection-manager-login-fails))

Now, I've tried to do what it says, but it doesn't work for me. So I created a new SSIS package to be testing around, it contains a Script task and its calling a simple Stored Procedure. The package Configuration contains only the ConnectionString property from the Connection Manager, and it looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <DTSConfiguration>
- <DTSConfigurationHeading>
  <DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="JohnSmith" GeneratedFromPackageName="Package" GeneratedFromPackageID="{2C421533-C76C-4583-841C-367C50DB61C1}" GeneratedDate="17/01/2017 --:--:-- p.m." /> 
  </DTSConfigurationHeading>
- <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[OLEDB_CONNECTION].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
  <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=ServerName;User ID=UserName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-Package-{C24F1A69-A9A3-40D4-8A1E-7EA61E0EB57D}ServerName.DatabaseName.UserName;Use Encryption for Data=False;Password=abc123;</ConfiguredValue> 
  </Configuration>
  </DTSConfiguration>
```

I added the **Password** at the end, just as the link at the start suggested, and tried to get the connetionString like this in the Script task:

```
String cn = Dts.Connections["OLEDB_CONNECTION"].ConnectionString;
```

and then calling it in the Stored Procedure, like this:

```
 using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cn))
 {
     using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("dbo.usp_sgn_conseguirNumDoc", con))
     {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@var_CODDOC", OleDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = "001"; 
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@var_NUMDOC", OleDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         result = Int64.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@var_NUMDOC"].Value.ToString());
     }
  }
```

but it fails in **con.Open()** so when I check the ConnectionString, its the same but without the **Password** value that I wrote. Its like it doesnt read it from the xml configuration file. When I checked the Message Tab in the Error List Window, I see this:

```
<DTS:ConnectionManager>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="DelayValidation">0</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">OLEDB_CONNECTION</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{C24F1A69-A9A3-40D4-8A1E-7EA61E0EB57D}</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description"></DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName">OLEDB</DTS:Property><DTS:ObjectData><DTS:ConnectionManager>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="Retain">0</DTS:Property><DTS:Password DTS:Name="Password" Sensitive="1"></DTS:Password>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConnectionString">Data Source=ServerName;User ID=UserName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-Package-{C24F1A69-A9A3-40D4-8A1E-7EA61E0EB57D}ServerName.DatabaseName.UserName;Use Encryption for Data=False;</DTS:Property></DTS:ConnectionManager></DTS:ObjectData></DTS:ConnectionManager>
```

Im out of ideas on what to do, any help will be appreciated

Im using Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Did you link your package to the config file like this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140213(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I did, and only linked the Connection String property, from Connection Managers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after a couple of days busting my head to the desk, managed to do it. It's a silly solution, but it wouldn't have crossed my mind in a thousand years! [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274080/ssis-connection-manager-not-storing-sql-password) helped me, not the accepted answer but this part right here:

> You can store the password in the configuration string by going to properties and adding password=yourpassword but very important put a space before 'password' word and after ';'

The fact that it worked blew my mind, something so simple and yet hard to find. After that, in a Script task I would use

```
String cn = Dts.Connections["OLEDB_CONNECTION"].ConnectionString;
```

and inside a Script Component (Data Flow Task) I had to configure the connection Manager tab (gave it the same name: OLEDB_CONNECTION), and then inside the script, I would use:

```
String cn = This.Connections.OLEDBCONNECTION.ConnectionString;
```

and it worked just fine!

Comment: Wow I didn't know that. Another way is to just use windows integrated authentication throughout. Then you don't need a password

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to do that, but it was specifically requested to me to use SQL Server authentication