# SSIS Package and DataSources tab's password

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS Job with one step that executes a package. On the datasources tab I have specified the password in a SQL Connection string because I can't connect using integrated security (I am using SQL Login).

So I went to DataSources, added Password=XXXXXX and then pressed ENTER and clicked OK. The job worked fine until today and I am wondering if the password got cleared because the server got re-started? Is this possible? and where are the passwords  saved?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1274080/6167855) seems to be related

Comment: Are you able to log in to the SQL Server instance using the SQL login with the same password?

Comment: Yes I am able to.