# SSIS Save Username and Password on ODBC Connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, ssis-2008, sql-job

I've created a System DSN uses IBM iSeries Access ODBC Driver. Then from ADO.NET ODBC Provider, I selected the System. When I run the package via BIDs all good.

But, when I deploy to SSIS Server (under job/msdb) and run the package it always fails with Password for user XXX on server is not correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Connection Manager Not Storing SQL Password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274080/ssis-connection-manager-not-storing-sql-password)